# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el texto de una traducción en Magento 2?

Tags: xml, magento2

Quiero cambiar el texto de estos dos bloques `authorization-link` y `register-link` en [magento2](/questions/tagged/magento2).

Los textos son: "Sign In" y "Create an Account".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asumo que lo deseas hacer en un theme, de ser así, debes apoyarte en la línea de comando para generar el csv respectivo y modificarlo en cada idioma de tu tienda:

```
php magento2/bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases --output="magento2/app/design/frontend/MiEmpresa/mitema/i18n/en_US.csv" magento2/app/design/frontend/MiEmpresa/mitema
```

Cambiando "MiEmpresa" y "mitema" por los directorios (o namespaces) respectivos del theme.

El ejemplo los genera para el idioma `en_US` , pero el proceso lo puedes repetir para el resto de idiomas de tu tienda: `es_ES`, `fr_FR`.

De resto es simplemente consultar el CSV generado y buscar el texto `"Sign In"` y `"Create an Account"` y sustituir el valor que está a la derecha por el deseado, manteniendo las comillas:

```
"Create an Account", "Crear una cuenta"
"Sign In", "Ingresar"
```

Más información en la documentación de Magento: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_practice.html